# How to add to an array with an if method

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I have an array of numbers like so...

```
a= [28, 67, 20, 38, 4, 39, 14, 84, 20, 64, 7, 24, 17, 8, 7, 6, 15, 52, 4, 26]
```

I need to check if each of the numbers is greater than 30 and if so then I want to count that number and get a count of how many numbers are greater than 30. I have this but it is not working so far

```
def late_items
    total_late = []
     if a.map { |i| i > 30}
      total_late << i
     end
    self.late_items = total_late.count
end
```

Comment: Do you want just the count of items or do you need the position of those items in the array as well?

Comment: `map` always returns something, so that `if` will never fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `count` method can be passed a block to specify what kind of elements should be counted. Elements for which the block returns `false` or `nil` are ignored.

In your case, it would boil down to this:

```
array.count { |element| element > 30 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select` to get all elements greater than 30.

```
a.select{|b| b > 30}.count
# => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is much simpler in Ruby:

```
a = [28, 67, 20, 38, 4, 39, 14, 84, 20, 64, 7, 24, 17, 8, 7, 6, 15, 52, 4, 26]

a.select{ |e| e > 30 }
```

Comment: This gives the values, but not the count.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you also want the index of each item that is over 30, if that is the case, this will work:

```
a= [28, 67, 20, 38, 4, 39, 14, 84, 20, 64, 7, 24, 17, 8, 7, 6, 15, 52, 4, 26]
count = 0
pos = []
a.each_with_index do |num, i|
    if num > 30
        count += 1
        pos << i
    end
end

puts count
print pos

#=> 6 [1,3,5,7,8,17]
```

Comment: This technically works, but leveraging more of the Enumerable library would significantly trim down how much work you have to do here.

Answer (score -1):

You may also check the `inject` method. Within it you can easily get the sum of numbers greater than 30:

```
a.inject(0) { |sum, n| n > 30 ? sum += n : sum }
```

Or, if you have an array of numbers greater than 30, you can use `reduce` to summarize its items. Within your `a` variable it will look like:

```
a.select{ |n| n > 30 }.reduce(&:+)
```

Comment: It does look a lot more clear as the second form. The fewer ternaries you have, the better.

Comment: These give the sum of the values, not the count.  Not what OP asked for.

Comment: "so then I want to count that number and get a count of how many numbers are greater than 30". As I understood from the 1st part of that sentence, he wanted to summarize those which are greater than 30 and also get the number of how much such numbers in the array.

Comment: @DannyOcean Still just seeing the word "count" there, not "sum" or "total".  Also, nothing in your two answers addresses "...get a count of how many numbers are greater than 30."